# Youtube videos not playing on all of my devices

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming

The main page opens just as it should, although when I click to start a video it doesn't play. I have already tried on 3 computers and 1 smartphone (Youtube app). As well as with different browsers, including Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

I think my ISP may have done this on purpose. What are the procedures for me to check if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your smartphone from your ISP network and connect it to some other network that is not served by your ISP. That should prove whether the ISP is responsible pretty quickly.

Unless of course it's being blocked at the router (accidentally or on purpose) and not by your ISP.